# How do I enable a button when fields are filled in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I'm trying to hide part of the form with the button disabled and have the user click on the button to show rest of form when previous fields are filled in.  Can anyone help?  Here's my code as an example:

HTML

```
<form>
<div id="group1">

        <label>Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field1"/><br/>
        <label>Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field2"/><br/>
        <label>Field 3:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field3"/><br/>

</div>

    <div align="center">
    <button id="show_form" onClick = "this.style.display= 'none'" disabled="disabled">
    Enter Billing Info</button>
    </div>

<div id="group2">

       <label>Field 4:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field4"/><br/>
       <label>Field 5:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field5"/><br/>
       <label>Field 6:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field6"/><br/>

</div>
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#group1').find('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    var flag = true;
    $('#group1').find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            flag = false;
            return;
        }
    });

    if (flag) {
        $("#show_form").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#show_form").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#group2").hide();

        $("#show_form").show();
    }
});

$("#group2").hide();

$("#show_form").click(function (){
    $("#group2").show();

    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#group1').find('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
        var flag = true;
        $('#group1').find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                flag = false;
                return;
            }
        });

        if (flag) {
            $("#show_form").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            /* This will hide the bottom form and disable the button again if
             * any of the field above will be emptied.
             * NOTE: This will just hide the form; it will not clear the fields.
             */
            $("#show_form").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#group2").hide();
        }
    });

    $("#group2").hide();
    $("#show_form").click(function (){
        $("#group2").show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

This will enable the button when all the fields in the initial form are filled. Then the user  will be able to click on the button to see the rest of the form.

Comment: This can't keep the track of fields being modified because the code who checks the inputs values is only executed once when the document is ready. Also It doesn't validate the fields to being filled on clicking the button

Comment: @academo Isn't it like the user wants to enable the button only when all the above fields are filled because he has initially set the button  to `disabled`?

Comment: Thank you.  This works great.  Is there a way to hide the second part of the form again if they decided to delete one of the previous fields?

Comment: Good point, I didn't see that disabled, the keyup should work but I think It is too much to run in each key up.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check if this works.
@academo Thanks! but if we not check the fields on each keyup then how can we know if any of the field is still empty?

Comment: quick question, how can i get this to show the 2nd part of the form when there are validation errors?  I can see the errors but I have to click the button to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop through each input and check if a value is set when the button is clicked like this:

```
$('#show_form').click(function () {
    var fields = $('.js-field');
    var pass = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (!$(fields[i]).val()) {
            pass = false;
        }
   }

    if (pass === true) {
        $('#group2').show();
    }
});
```

I also needed to add some classes to your html:

```
<form>
<div id="group1">

        <label>Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field1 js-field"/><br/>
        <label>Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field2 js-field"/><br/>
        <label>Field 3:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field3 js-field"/><br/>

</div>

 <button type="button" id="show_form" value="Show_Form">Enter Billing     
 Info</button>

<div id="group2" style="display: none;">

       <label>Field 4:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field4"/><br/>
       <label>Field 5:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field5"/><br/>
       <label>Field 6:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field6"/><br/>

</div>
</form>
```

To see it in action visit this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3skdkwt/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add some logic to the click event and check all the input fields to have a value like this

```
$("#show_form").click(function(){
   var allFilled = true;

   $('#group1').find('input').each(function(){
      //if someone is empty allFilled will keep false
      if(this.value === ''){
         allFilled = false;
         //this breaks the each
         return false;
      }
   });

   if(allFilled){
       $("#group2").show();
   }
});
```

Keep in mind the previous code only work with input fields.